# Matrix report data via analytics API

Tags: api, analytics

I am trying to write code for creating reports in pdf format. I could see example for traversing tabular report using analytics api. But I am not able to understand how to traverse for summary or matrix report using analytics api.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference for traversing tabular, summary and matrix reports is factmap. You have to find groupingdown for summary report, groupingdown and groupingacross for matrix report. then iterate through them accordingly and can retrieve values by appropriate factmap.
Factmap for reports:
Tabular: !T
Summary : Gropingdown.key ! T
Matrix : Groupingdown.key ! Groupingacross.key